# Extensions on the remote machine are not recognized by Remote-SSH extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

I have a Linux machine with VSCode on it, with extensions installed at /home/myuser/.vscode/extensions/. Everything runs great. However, now I would like to connect to that machine remotely with "Remote - SSH" from a VSCode instance that runs on another computer. The connection was successful, but the extensions are all grayed-out and have "Install in SSH:..." buttons.

How can I get VSCode to find the extensions already installed on the remote (Linux) machine?

The extensions were installed using VSCode *on* the remote machine.

I looked through the settings for something that might have to do with it, but couldn't find. I didn't install anything remotely yet ("Install in SSH:...") because I was afraid that it might clash with the existing installation.

Comment: the remote VSC runs a different VSC than when run from the local (linux) command prompt, the have the same versions, on linux look in the directory `~/.vscode-server`

Comment: Aha! That path is just what I was missing. I made a soft link to the existing extension directory and it seems to work fine now. Thank you so much!